# all asp tags showing warning in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

pls help............

All of my **asp tags like `<asp:Button />,<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>`,etc.,
Showing warning**. And i cannot access recognized those asp tags by click 
**ctrl+ space**

thanks in advance..........

example codes attached below.....`<asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Extn/img/database_edit.gif" />`

this `<asp:imagebutton>` showing warning

Comment: Does it compile and run correctly?

Comment: What warning it is showing?

Comment: the error is element' XXXX' not found......i got the answer by deleting the folder.... `C:\Users\[your_nt_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is

> element' XXXX' not found......

I got the answer by deleting the folder.

```
C:\Users\[your_nt_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\ReflectedSchemas
```